# How to join with multi-value columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

```
Game and Developer
```

My Game table has the following columns:

```
Release Date Origin Date DeveloperID
```

and my Developer table has the following columns:

```
DevId Games
```

With data, the tables might look something like this:

```
Game:
Release Date Origin Date GameId
  11/20/2017  11/09/2015    G-1
  06/07/1999  03/04/1995    G-2
  08/31/2015  02/09/2010    G-3
```

The Developer table might look like:

```
DevId Games
 D-1   G-1, G-2
 D-2   G-3
 D-3   G1, G2, G3
```

Games can have multiple values and they're selected in a drop-down list.

I want to create a Relationship between the Games values and the GameId of the Game table and concatenate the Release Date and the Origin Date for each of the Games associated with the Dev.

So for D1, I would want something like

```
D1 Dates - 11/20/2017, 11/09/2017, 06/07/1999, 03/04/1995 since G-1 and G-2 are associated with D1 
D2 Dates - only 08/31/2015, 02/09/2010
D3 Dates - 11/20/2017, 11/09/2015, 06/07/1999, 03/04/1995, 08/31/2015, 092/09/2010 since all of the Games are associated with this Dev.
```

What I have right now doesn't cut it. It's not grouping appropriately and just lists 6 rows as

```
11/20/2017
11/09/2015
06/07/1999 
03/04/1995
08/31/2015
02/09/2010
```

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT [Origin Date] & ',' & [Release Date] FROM Game INNER JOIN Developer ON Game.GameId = Developer.Games.Value;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL, SQL-Server, or MS Access? Please remove the tags for the other databases.

Comment: You should normalize your table design, multl-valued columns are a bad idea in relational databases.

Comment: Replace the multi-value column with a many-to-many table.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, Access.

Comment: @Bamar I agree, but it's not my call to change it.

Comment: What is the maximum number of Games that a developer has made?

Comment: @VishnuKunchur Hey there, it can change. No max.

Comment: Can you use another database like PostGRESQL? Or do you HAVE TO do this in Access?

Comment: @VishnuKunchur Unforunately Access, per school.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the number of games are limited to 3. If this is not the case, you may have to write another subquery to find the maximum number of games and construct an equivalent number of columns.

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT DevID, g_1, g_2, g_3
FROM
(
SELECT DevID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_num1 FROM DevID
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT a[1] AS g_1, a[2] AS g_2, a[3] AS g_3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_num2
FROM
(
SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY(games, ',')
FROM DevID
) AS dt(a)
) b
ON a.row_num1 = b.row_num2
) 

SELECT DevId, ARRAY_AGG(release_date) AS release_dates, ARRAY_AGG(origin_date) AS origin_dates
FROM
(
SELECT DevID, game, Release_date, Origin_date
FROM
(
SELECT DevID, LTRIM(game) AS game
FROM
(
SELECT DevId, g_1 AS game FROM cte WHERE g_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT DevId, g_2 AS game FROM cte WHERE g_2 IS NOT NUll
UNION
SELECT DevId, g_3  AS game FROM cte WHERE g_3 IS NOT NULL
) a1
) al
LEFT JOIN
Game g1
ON al.game = g1.GameId
) al1 
GROUP BY DevId
```

Output:

```
DevId   ReleaseDates     OriginDates
"D-2"   "{2015-08-31}"  "{2010-02-09}"
"D-3"   "{2017-11-20,1999-06-07,2015-08-31}"    "{2015-11-09,1995-03-04,2010-02-09}"
"D-1"   "{2017-11-20,1999-06-07}"   "{2015-11-09,1995-03-04}"
```

Comment: My bad, I dont think you can use CTEs with MS Access. I'm going to reformat this.

Answer (score 0):

When working with "multi-valued" fields you tend to have to resort to stuff like this:

```
Games = GameId
OR Games LIKE GameId & ',*'
OR Games LIKE '*, ' & GameId & ',*'
OR Games LIKE '*, ' & GameId
```

*My MSAccess syntax is a bit rusty, so that may not be exactly correct.*

---

```
SELECT g.[Origin Date] & ',' & g.[Release Date] 
FROM Game AS g
INNER JOIN Developer AS d
ON d.Games = g.GameId
    OR d.Games LIKE g.GameId & ',*'
    OR d.Games LIKE '*, ' & g.GameId & ',*'
    OR d.Games LIKE '*, ' & g.GameId
;
```

Comment: The select portion should not change; this, after a minor edit for concatenation shortly, should replace your ON conditions.

Comment: So like a WHERE? Where are you joining?

Comment: Added full query

Comment: I don't think this is Access compliant, aren't you joining on the same table?

Comment: What do you mean by "joining on the same table"? The query is exactly the same other than having different join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store multiple values in a single column!  That is not how databases work.

Sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really, really, really, really bad designs.  You can do:

```
SELECT g.[Origin Date] & ',' & g.[Release Date]
FROM Game as g INNER JOIN
     Developer as d
     ON ',' & d.Games & ',' LIKE '*,' & g.GameId & ',*';
```

Perhaps in MS Access, you need to do this as a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
  SELECT g.[Origin Date] & ',' & g.[Release Date]
FROM Game as g,
     Developer as d
WHERE ',' & d.Games & ',' LIKE '*,' & g.GameId & ',*';
```

Comment: This isn't working, saying it joins on the same name.

Comment: @Darnold14 . . . I don't know what that error could be referring to.

Comment: Don’t you need to join on a field? Like On field = field

Comment: This is stating it is an ambiguous join.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are supposed to do override the lookup properties doing the following:

- Create a query that is based on your `Developer` table, add both fields to the query.
- Rename the field `Games` into `Dates` (Enter `Dates: Games` as the second field)
- Change the lookup properties of that field as follows:

  - Display: ComboBox
  - RowsourceType: Table/Query
  - RowSource: `SELECT Game.DeveloperID, Game.[Release Date] & ", " & Game.[Origin Date] AS Expr1 FROM Game;`
  - Bound Column: 1
  - Column Count: 2
  - Column Widths: 0 (=hide the first column)
  - List Width: 0 (=Automatic)

Although this doesn't really concatenate the dates, they will be *displayed* as if they were (the way that multi-valued fields display multiple values).

The result of the German version (with semicolon as list separator) looks like this:

[image]